# Is MySQL/PHP the best way to go for this project?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been tasked with this project and before I start any coding or even drawing anything on paper, I want to be sure that MySQL/PHP is the best way to go. Here's what I've got:

Myself and another student will be making a database of articles and 'tagging' them with design terms. So, for example, an article regarding power consumption issues in a hotel could be tagged with 'power conservancy' or something to that effect.

Also, the database will be searchable, both by tag and by article description or title/author.

So, what I'm thinking is this -

The front-end consists of a basic form where the user selects to either search by Tag(s), Article description (where the search would be compared against the article description, not the actual article text which may be a scanned image), or the title/author combination.

When the search is performed a simple list is displayed with the results from the query.

The database itself would consist of 1 table with the following rows:

ID, TAGS, AUTHOR, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ARTICLE

Where ID is an auto incrementing INT

TAGS, AUTHOR, TITLE, and DESCRIPTION will all be VARCHARs

and ARTICLE will be a BLOB (because it will be a PDF, .DOC, .DOCX, .TXT, or .RTF

The search results will, when clicked, change to the full view of the article, which will display the article along with the associated information.

Does that sound like the best way to go?

Any input is much appreciated as this is only my 2nd deployed MySQL/PHP app.

Comment: Sounds like it will work. However, I wouldn't use a BLOB if I were you.

Comment: [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) these kinds of questions often are too vague, there are hundreds of platforms to build web apps on, and just as many database backends.  What makes one better for one task might make it equally weaker for another task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I disagree with store the article in a BLOB, you can store in the filesystem.

php and mysql can be very good, but you can consider mongoDB and ElasticSearch for this database.